# Get url kwargs in class based views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I need to retrieve the value of the pk written in the url in my class based view:

```py
path('<int:pk>/data/', views.DataView.as_view(), name='data'),
```

However, what I saw everywhere was the pk retrieved in the definition of methods like `get` or `post`.

What I want is to be able to use it to define my class variables, because I need to do get the same value from this pk in every method inside my class, like below:

```py
class DataView(ContextMixin, UpdateView):
    pk = get_pk_from_url
    ...
    value = ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.value
        # Do something with value

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.value
        # Do something with value
```

I got an idea while writing this question, which is to define a method that will do what I need, then calling this method in my other methods.

```py
class DataView(ContextMixin, UpdateView):

    def get_value(self):
        self.pk = self.kwargs['script_id']
        ...
        self.value = ...

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):  
        self.get_value()
        value = self.value
        # Do something with value

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.get_value()
        value = self.value
        # Do something with value
```

However, I don't know if there's another way, which is why I still wanna ask my question.

Comment: You can override the `setup` method: this is triggered *before* the `get`/`post`, so reduces the amount of duplicated code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to [@WillemVanOnsem's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67579/willem-van-onsem) comment, I was able to use the `setup` method (doc [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/4.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.setup)) in order to define everything I needed to define.
So in the end I get something like that :

```
class DataView(View):

    def setup(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.pk = kwargs['pk']
        ...
        self.value = ...
        return super().setup(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.value
        

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.value
```

The `setup` method being called before the `get` and `post` ones, the class attributes declared in it can then be used in the other methods.